# Python list of dictionaries from four different lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Can someone help me with creating a list of dictionaries in Python.

I want to convert the below lists into list of dictionaries in Python.

```
        value1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
        value2 = ['6.0',  '8.5', '7.0', '9.5']
        value3 = [500, 600, 900, 750]
        value4 = ['$$','$$$','$', '$$']


        keys = ['name', 'rate', 'rev', 'amount']

The output list of dictionaries should look like this:

  [ {'name':'name1', 'rate':'6.0', 'rev':500, 'amount':'$$'},  
    {'name':'name2', 'rate':'8.5', 'rev':600, 'amount':'$$$'},  
    {'name':'name3', 'rate':'7.0', 'rev':900, 'amount':'$'},  
    {'name':'name4', 'rate':'9.5', 'rev':750, 'amount':'$$'} ]

Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension, like this

```
value1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
value2 = ['6.0',  '8.5', '7.0', '9.5']
value3 = [500, 600, 900, 750]
value4 = ['$$','$$$','$', '$$']


results = [{'name':name, 'rate':rate, 'rev':rev, 'amount':amount} for name, rate, rev, amount in zip(value1, value2, value3, value4)]
```

This gives you a list of dictionaries:

```
[{'amount': '$$', 'name': 'name1', 'rate': '6.0', 'rev': 500},
 {'amount': '$$$', 'name': 'name2', 'rate': '8.5', 'rev': 600},
 {'amount': '$', 'name': 'name3', 'rate': '7.0', 'rev': 900},
 {'amount': '$$', 'name': 'name4', 'rate': '9.5', 'rev': 750}]
```

We can use `zip` to take one value from `value1`, `value2`, `value3` and `value4` at a time and feed them into each dictionary in the list. We then iterate over this list object with list comprehension.

Comment: @Murali great, please mark it as the correct answer if it is what you are looking for. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
value1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
value2 = ['6.0',  '8.5', '7.0', '9.5']
value3 = [500, 600, 900, 750]
value4 = ['$$','$$$','$', '$$']
results = [dict(zip(['name', 'rate', 'rev', 'amount'], i)) for i in zip(*[value1, value2, value3, value4])]
```

Output:

```
[{'amount': '$$', 'rate': '6.0', 'rev': 500, 'name': 'name1'}, {'amount': '$$$', 'rate': '8.5', 'rev': 600, 'name': 'name2'}, {'amount': '$', 'rate': '7.0', 'rev': 900, 'name': 'name3'}, {'amount': '$$', 'rate': '9.5', 'rev': 750, 'name': 'name4'}]
```

Comment: Nice work, @Ajax. It will look even more elegant if you use the list keys that Murali has specified inside your list comprehension.